# Rails Uniqueness: true model with a DB with has_many references - Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model

I have a problem. I need to set a model of `report_templates` unique in my database in relation to the `classroom`, each `classroom` has only one `report_template`.
But in my DB, I already have a classroom with multiple `report_templates`.

is it safe to add this validation to `report_template` model upload to staging?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:-

1. If you add validation then you will get error when you are editing existing report templates. This is because validations are called when you save the record. So you might have to remove the duplicate/multiple records manually via console or db or a rake task.
   Simply accessing the record will not throw an error.
2. If one classroom has only report template do you think it is better to use either of below? I do not know the exact scenario so cannot suggest an approach.

- has_one association
- belongs_to association

Thank you.